# Submitting a form value straight into the URL?

Tags: html, url, variables, coldfusion

i've created a paginator for my search function on my site. The paginator works perfectly fine, so does the search function. However, the issue i have is i'm having to use excess code just to pass through the value of the form to run the query with. Ideally, i want it so that when i press the submit button + the page submits, it posts the value from the form straight into the URL as a URL variable, however currently i am submitting it, checking to see if the form in question is defined, then storing that value into a variable, passing that variable through the URL's of all the page links which then stores it as a URL variable. I want to cut out this middle man and make it a URL variable from the word go. Any suggestions? Thanks guys.

```
<cfif IsDefined("form.search")>
    <cfset search = form.search>
</cfif>

<cfquery datasource="test.datasource" name="findbands">
    Select test_band
    From test
    Where test_band LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#search#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
</cfquery>


<FORM action="band_search.cfm" method="post">
    <INPUT type="text" name="search"></INPUT>
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Go"></INPUT>
</FORM>

<cfoutput query="findbands" startrow="1" maxrows="10">
    #currentrow#) #test_band#
</cfoutput>

<cfif IsDefined("search")>
    <cfset link = CGI.script_name & "?search=" & search>
    <A href="#link#>Previous</A>
</cfif>

<cfif IsDefined("search")>
    <cfset link = CGI.script_name & "?search=" & search>
    <A href="#link#>Next</A>
</cfif>
```

I haven't demonstrated it above, but i have got some code which passes a URL variable editing the start row and calculating the total amount of pages. However that is irrelevant. The solution i need is when submitting the form i can just use the URL.search rather than having to create the variable search as shown. Thanks.

Comment: can you show some code? or illustrate better what you want to achieve?

Comment: As stated, how do you pass a form value straight into the URL as a URL variable on submission?

Comment: what do you mean with URL variable? something like this? `http://myurl.com?var=foo`

Comment: Exactly that yes. So if i enter the term "bea" into my search box, on submit my site goes www.testsite.com/bands/band_search?search=bea into the URL.

Comment: and do you submit the form using jquery?

Comment: Nope, no jQuery used, trying to make it all work without jQuery then using that to improve it.

Comment: What's preventing you from using `<form method='get'>`? That'd be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Because isn't that getting data? The data doesn't exist yet so how can it retrieve it?

Comment: Busches question and your answer are exactly why you need to display code.

Comment: "Get" simply specifies that the form fields will be attached as URL parameters rather "POST" which is done as an internal part of the request.

Comment: @LeeB: Check my update, I think I'm get it now ;) but you should follow the advises on this thread, `GET` is for that if you just want to send the search value

Comment: Is there anyway you could post your statement as an answer Tom? I'll mark it as correct for you. I apologise for earlier stating you were incorrect, just tried this method="get" and first click it's plonked "search=a" into my URL. Thanks a lot guys, been frying my brain for hours.

Comment: I'm still not seeing a reason why you can't use `GET` and have it do what you want. You could also just reference `form.Search` instead of having to do `<cfset Search = form.Search />`, as your `isDefined("search")` will return the form.Search value anyway, but to each their own.

Comment: @Busches that would be making trivial mistakes as this has been troubling me all afternoon. The GET method worked, thanks again.

Comment: Please add some validation checking to all of your form/url variables and also use `<cfqueryparam>` in your queries.

Comment: @Miguel-F i already do but for the sake of speed i chose not to include them above. Don't worry i'm aware of SQL injections + sanitizing input data.

Comment: @Miguel-F there are quite a few things that should be updated, unscoped variables, `##` in `<cfset>` ending `</INPUT>`, etc. Not to mention in the example the previous and next links are identical. Just assuming they're there because it's just a sample.

Comment: @Busches I always end in </INPUT>, prefer it that way. However, no, i don't use ## within <cf> tags, i did it for those who might not be CF friendly to understand what they were, and i do scope my variables too. Also as stated, i quickly mashed the above together to provide an example.

Comment: _"i did it for those who might not be CF friendly"_ - !?! You added CF-specific superfluous syntax to make the code easier to understand for people that don't know the syntax? :/

Comment: _"but for the sake of speed i chose not to include them above."_ - Well for the sake of not providing a bad example to future visitors, I fixed it. :)

Comment: It's not really a bad example, there's nothing wrong with what i provided. It's called an example for a reason, not supposed to be the real thing.

Comment: I disagree entirely - examples are _examples_. They are what new/unfamiliar people see first/most, and thus should (ideally) be idiomatic to the language, and - at the very least - not promoting bad practises. If the query isn't a key part, it can be represented along the lines of `<!--- [[ insert db query using url.search var ]] --->` or with appropriate pseudo-code.

Comment: (oh, and putting a user-provided variable directly into a query *is* a ***very*** bad practise - if you don't understand why, please do not write code for any public websites!)

Comment: Once again, part of the example, i will have stringent checks on the field to ensure code that shouldn't be entered, can't be entered into the search bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a method of "get" rather than "post". It will attach all inputs to the action string as URL parameters.

Change the line:

```
<FORM action="band_search.cfm" method="post">
```

to:

```
<FORM action="band_search.cfm" method="get">
```

Comment: As stated, i need to submit the FORM value straight into the URL. This cannot be done using a link.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a parametter with the POST form with jQuery like this:

```
$(".submit").click(function() { 
    //gettting the value
    var search_val = $('input#search').val();
    //add hidden input
    $("#formID").append("<input type='hidden' name='search' value='"+search_val+"' />").submit(); 
});
```

#### EDIT:

Maybe this is not the better way to do this, but if you just want to pass the parameter via url, you can change the action of the form before submit the form.

```
$(".submit").click(function() { 
     //gettting the action of the form
     var action = $("#formID").attr("action");
     //changing the value of the form
     action += "?search="+$('input#search').val();
     //Now submit the form
     $("#formID").attr("action", action ).submit(); 
});
```

**UPDATE:** After update your question, I think you just need to change `POST` for `GET` ;)

Comment: This is pretty much the same as what i already have. I'll edit my post to show an example.

Comment: I know don't worry. I'd mark the question up but don't have enough rep yet.